# Cakephp one model different form validation

Tags: validation, cakephp-2.0

I have a model name "User", their I added a validation for login. But I need to validate registration page also. Fields for both forms are different.
Can someone please tell me how to manage different form validation with 1 model.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate as many fields as you want inside your User model, it does not matter in which View or in which form you input them.
So just add the fields from your registration page to the User's $validate inside your User model.

Answer (score 0):

If all forms share similar fieldnames but require different validation rules you can use: 
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/dardosordi/2008/07/29/multivalidatablebehavior-using-many-validation-rulesets-per-model

If the duplicate fields validate the same on all forms you can just add them all to the Model, it will only validate the ones present on the form.

Remember to NOT use 'required' => true, setting this key to true will make the field always required and it has to be present in the data array even if it's not on your form